# Is System Restore a full Restore and suitable for a test installation?

Tags: windows-7, backup, system-restore, disk-image

I have a fresh and activated Windows 7 installation that I would like to use as a Test installation. So I would like to create a Snapshot and be able to completely revert to that snapshot.

As it's not Enterprise/Ultimate, VHD Booting is not an option, and as it's a Netbook, VMWare/VPC is not an option either.

So I wonder if System Restore is good enough, or if I need an imaging solution? (If it helps: I have a Windows Home Server)

I should add that the HD has 2 partitions, and on both are Windows 7 installations. The second partition should be left untouched as this is the main Setup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

System restore is very good now, but it still doesn't beat a full on backup - if you get a virus or anything really serious, you will be in trouble.

Windows comes with a backup utility that can create a full image, I highly recommend you do this to another computer or a external drive.

[image]

When you want to restore, you can just have a bootable USB windows disk, go to repair and as long as you have network or direct access to the image, you will be able to easily restore.

[image]

(Third one down)

Comment: Nice, i didn't know that this stuff is now built in, and it's even available in the Starter Edition. That will work :)

Answer (score 1):

System Restore is not good enough. and neither is the System Image feature if you ever want to test other operating systems than Windows 7 on that drive/partition (Microsoft either care very little or they're in a state of deep neglect when it comes to Linux OS :).

My favorites are Symantec Ghost Enterprise and Drive Snapshot (both commercial products), if you're looking for some decent free drive imaging tools, have a look at Clonezilla, DriveImageXML or EASEUS Disk Copy.

Comment: then you're fine with the onboard tools :)